# React: How do I move my ajax api call into a separate component?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, reactjs, refactoring

Here is a typical container component that is working perfectly well:

```
const API = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { profiles: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchProfiles();
    }

    fetchProfiles() {
      let url = API;
      fetch(url)
        .then( (res) => res.json() )
        .then( (data) => {
          let results = data.results;
          this.setState({
            profiles: results 
          });
        })
        .catch( (error) => console.log('Oops! . There Is A Problem', error) );
    }

    render() {
      // rendering child component here
    }
}

export default App;
```

What I am trying to do now is move the `fetchProfiles` function into a separate *api* component.

So I make a `profiles.js` file in an `api` folder in my project:

```
const API = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';

export function fetchProfiles() {
  let url = API;
  fetch(url)
  .then( (res) => res.json() );
}
```

And now my main component imports it and uses it like so:

```
import { fetchProfiles } from '../api/profiles.js';


const API = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { profiles: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      fetchProfiles.then((data) => {
        let results = data.results;
          this.setState({
            profiles: results 
          });
      });
    }

  // render call etc
```

But when I run the call in `componentDidMount` like this, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: _profiles.fetchProfiles.then is not a function`. I am trying to chain with `then` because the fetch api returns `res.json()` as a promise.

I tried wrapping `fetchProfiles` in a outer function, in a new promise too! But nothing works!! What am I doing wrong here? Please help with this refactoring.

Comment: You need to return `fetch(url)` itself, so you'll return a promise and then you can use `then` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to return `fetch(url)` itself, so you'll return a promise and then you can use `then` method:

```
const API = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';

export function fetchProfiles() {
  let url = API;

  // return the promise itself
  return fetch(url).then( (res) => res.json() );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The way I fixed this was to return `fetch(url)` itself:

```
const API = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';

export function fetchProfiles() {
    let url = API;
    return fetch(url)
      .then( (response) => response.json() );
}
```

Then in the container component:

```
    componentDidMount() {
      fetchProfiles()
        .then( (data) => {
          let results = data.results;
          this.setState({
            profiles: results
          });
        });
    }
```

This now works!!

Answer (score 0):

I once made a similar app that i separated the API calls from the context (i used context API btw) instead of returning the fetch function and handle the async calls on the context, i handled everything on the function declared on the API and on the context only recieved the result, this seems to be a little bit more complicated but it simplifies the data handling on the context and all the data fetching login on the other side, i also used axios for the API call but it's easily swapped with the fetch one (axios handles better errors like handling of timeouts or service not available)

on profiles.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';    

export const fetchProfiles = async () => {
    let url = API;
    try{
      const response = await axios.get(url)
      const data = response.data
      return data
    }catch(error) {
      console.log('failed to fetch Profiles')
      throw Error(error)
    }
}
```

on the context:

```
import { fetchProfiles} from "../API/profiles";

const getProfiles = async () =>{
  const result = await fetchProfiles();
  this.setState({
    profiles: result
  });
}
```